# Searching for a node in a tree structure

Tags: c++, tree, structure, traversal

I need help finding and returning a "node" in a general tree structure. Each node can have more than 2 children so it's not a binary tree. I've been given the following code, this Element object has a list to contain its children, I create one element node pointer in main and using that I have to add and search for children. This is for a school project but I'm not looking for answers (an answer wouldn't hurt). Any advice on how to go about this problem would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Element
{
  private:
  list<Element*> children;
  char* _tag;
  int _value;
  // private methods
  public:
  // default constructor
  Element();
  // non-default constructors
  Element( char* name); // value is set to -99 if not given
  Element(char* name, char* value);
  // destructor, must recursively destruct its children
  // and release the memory allocated for _tag
  ~Element();
  // ostream operator ( pre-order traversal)
  friend ostream&  operator << (ostream& out, const Element& E);
  void display_xml(); // print out the tree in xml-- format
  void addChild( Element* child); // add a child
  // Find the first element such that _tag == tag
  // returns “this” pointer of this element
  Element* findTag( char* tag);
  char* getName();
  int getValue();
  void setName(char* name);
  void setValue( int value);
  int height(); //b return the height
  int size(); // return the size
  // other methods
};
```

this is my best attempt at a solution, it has obvious problems but I'm new to all of this and some explanation on a proper solution, or some sample code would be very helpful!

```
Element* Element::findTag(char* tag)
{
    list<Element*> temp = children;
    int s = temp.size();

    if(getName() == tag)
    {
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            findTag((*temp.front()).getName());
            temp.pop_front();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a pseudo-code for searching for a node that has a value `val` in a tree rooted at `root`:

```
find(Node root, val)
    if(root.value == val) return root         //-- if the recursion found the node we are searching for
else
    for every child x of root                //-- re-cursing on the children of root 
        if(find(x, val) != null) return x    //-- if one of the calls found the node we are searching for
    return null                              //-- if we did not find the node we want in the sub-tree rooted at root
```